# Sum function issue PostgreSQL 9.4.5

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, postgresql-9.4

I am executing a query that makes a sum of some values of the database, the data type of the column is real, but it shows me the result without the decimal part, I would like to know what is the problem because I have many values with decimals.
The query:

```
select extract(Month from date)||'/'|| extract(Year from date) as month_year, 
sum(value) as total
from my_sum_table
where extract(Year from date) =2018 and 
extract(Month from date) between 01 and 05 group by extract(Month from 
date),extract(Year from date) order by extract(Month from date)
```

And I get this:

[image]

When I have values like these:

[image]

Comment: Please add a mockup of you table+data and show us what you have tried

Comment: There's what I'm doing, I added the query and the resultset.

Comment: @DavidLeonardoCrespín, you need to also share the table schema for `my_sum_table`. we can't run your query because we don't have `my_sum_table` as you do. Also, please replace screenshots with a textual representation of the data.

Comment: Ok, thank you, yes I can do that, but you can try as the user The Impaler does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I verified that real is to small to store the value that I need, so I am missing the digits of decimals, I have to change the data type.

Answer (score 0):

You may be missing something in your explanation. I just tried your query in PostgreSQL 9.4 and works flawlessly:

```
create table my_sum_table (
  date date,
  value real
);

insert into my_sum_table (date, value) values ('2018-01-01', 130.59);
insert into my_sum_table (date, value) values ('2018-01-02', 256.49);
insert into my_sum_table (date, value) values ('2018-02-15', 712.57);

select extract(Month from date)||'/'|| extract(Year from date) as month_year, 
  trunc(sum(value::double precision)::numeric, 2) as total
  from my_sum_table
  where extract(Year from date) =2018 and 
    extract(Month from date) between 01 and 05 group by extract(Month from 
    date),extract(Year from date) order by extract(Month from date);
```

Result:

```
month_year                                          total            
---------------------------------------------------------------------
1/2018                                              387.07999        
2/2018                                              712.57001
```

Just fyi, the resulting column `total` is of type `float4`.

Also, you show the resulting month as `01/2018` instead of `1/2018`. This means, you are **post-processing** the result. It seems the problem in on that post-processing, and not in the PostgreSQL query.

Comment: No, Im not post-processing the result, was my mistake, just was an example, Im doing the same like you.

Comment: OK, so are you still getting an integer sum? In my example above, I get the **float4** sum, as you see.

Comment: Yes I have an integer sum.

Comment: Using the database manager DBeaver shows me the result with decimals, now I want to truncate the result to two decimals, Im trying with this function trunc(sum(value)::numeric,2) but I get the result like this:                               
1/2018 318993.00
2/2018 175941.00
3/2018 184576.00
4/2018 315935.00
5/2018 319908.00

Comment: Works for me: `trunc(sum(value)::numeric,2)` returns **387.08** and **712.57**

Comment: Ah... `real` is too small and you are losing the last digits in the sum. I was able to reproduce your case.

Comment: You need to promote the values to `double precision` before adding them. Try: `trunc(sum(value::double precision)::numeric,2)`

Comment: I tried your suggestion with double precision but the result is incorrect for example without trunc I get: `1/2018  |318992.719 |` and with trunc: `1/2018  |318992.91 |`